# Register JavaScript from within a UserControl in ASP.NET

Tags: javascript, asp.net

I declare my javascript in the design page of a usercontrol (ascx). Is there a way to register this javascript block in the Head section? I don't want to use ClientScript.RegisterClientScriptBlock as I don't want to declare my javascript in the code-behind. I also cannot move it (entirely) into a separate file, because I use business logic to create it.

Comment: What do you mean with "I don't want to declare my javascript in the code-behind"? If you are talking about registering javascript code from a user control on page header, code behind logic will be involved in one way or another.

Comment: place your control in the Head section?

Comment: I mean I don't want to create the javascript in the code-behind (string a = "myfun() { .. }"). I would like (if possible) to delcare it inside a container on the design page and register it somehow in the code-behind in the head/bottom body section

Comment: What's the point of moving it to `head`? It'll run fine where it is. If you need something to only happen once regardless of the number of user controls on the page, `RegisterClientScriptBlock` is the proper tool.

Comment: I need it to be in either in the head or in the bottom of the body. It will run everywhere, of course. However, for best page-rendering it is better to put all JS code in the bottom of the page.

Answer (score 2):

I would say that ClientScript.RegisterClientScriptBlock is the  way to register scripts from user/custom controls. But as you don't want to put the script in code-behind, you can write the relevant code in ascx page inside server tags. For example,

```
<script runat="server">

protected override OnPreRender(sender as object, e as EventArgs)
{
   base.onPreRender(sender, e);

   string script;
   // Logic to build the script goes here

   this.Page.ClientScript.RegisterClientScriptBlock(this.GetType(), "Key_" + this.ClientID, script, true);
}

</script>
```